# Is there a C++ smart pointer that represents a terminal pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm playing around with smart pointers in C++, using `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` and `weak_ptr`.  Let's say I have a `shared_ptr` that I share among multiple owners, but I have a set of consumers that want to use the pointer, but not assume ownership of it.

I am assuming then, I could use a `weak_ptr` like this:

```
class control_base {        
    std::weak_ptr<control_base> parent;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<control_base>> children;
        
    control_base( const std::shared_ptr<control_base> & _parent ) : parent(_parent)
    {
    }           
};

class page {
    std::shared_ptr<control_base> root;
};
```

In the above example then, a `control_base` node would be referenced as a `shared_ptr` via the child member.  the node has a reference to a parent, which is weak.  This avoids the circular free problem, and, the lock on weak protects against the parent being freed before the child.  If I assign or delete root, or frankly, an element in the tree, all the children of that node are freed.

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: So a wrapper around a leaked pointer? What use case do you have in mind?

Comment: "_that the pointer is not going to be freed, but I can still access it_": I don't understand what you mean here. Are you saying that this should point to an object that is never supposed to be freed, a pointer that will be freed by the caller instead of the callee or a pointer that has already been freed (in which case accessing would be UB)? A [mre] demonstrating the intended usage would be more helpful than only a text description.

Comment: Your question uses very confusing words. What is a `dead pointer` ? A pointer does not have any sense of self-awareness. If you can access  a pointer you can free it.

Comment: Perhaps you are after `gsl::not_null` or `gsl::owner`  from the GSL? (https://github.com/microsoft/GSL)

Comment: "I want a wrapper for an allocation that is *forbidden*." Well, okay, just take it out of anyone's scope who *might* use it.

Comment: I edited the question.  The proper term I suppose is a dangling pointer, where, you may have a pointer whose lifetime is managed being shared with a consumer that you don't want to have ownership of the pointer.

Comment: The structure you have here doesn't need a `weak_ptr` and `shared_ptr` at all. A tree has unique ownership: The parent owns the child and the ownership is already managed by the vector, so `unique_ptr` isn't required either. The pointer to the parent can be a raw pointer.

Comment: @TJBandrowsky Are you sure "dangling pointer" is the correct term? It means a pointer with an invalid pointer value, specifically a pointer that used to point to an object but that object's lifetime has ended. Typically associated with `delete ptr;` where `ptr` is now a dangling pointer and can't be dereference.

Comment: _the lock on weak protects against the parent being freed before the child_ -> locking the `weak_ptr` prevents the parent from being freed while the child is trying to access it, is how I personally would phrase it, but I think you've got the right idea.  Note that `std::weak_ptr::lock` returns an empty `shared_ptr` if the parent no longer exists.  @user17732522 is right to to say that none of this is actually necessary here, but I appreciate that you are using this code as a means to understand how the `shared_ptr` / `weak_ptr` mechanism works.

Comment: Documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock.  Your edit has greatly improved the question btw, voted to reopen.

Comment: A you looking for the term "observer pointer"? They're semi-codified by [`std::experimental::observer_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr), which is just a raw pointer that expressly does not own the watched object

Comment: Thank you all for excellent feedback.  I truly appreciate you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your example could have sufficed with just raw pointers, your interpretation is completely correct. The child nodes will deconstruct when their parent's deconstruct. And locking the parent weak pointer successfully (getting a nonnull shared_ptr from it) will defer the freeing of that parent pointer as long as you hold the returned shared_ptr. :D